# PHP if child of display this HTML, else display that HTML

Tags: php, html, wordpress, if-statement

First question on here. I am doing a custom `Wordpress` site and I need to divide the post page (single.php) so that if it is a child of my WORK page it displays a certain HTML, else it displays another chunk of HTML.

At the moment I have the following inside the `single.php` file:

```
<div class="work_section">
<p>WORK SECTION GOES HERE</p>
</div>
<!--div:work_section -->

<div class="news_section">
<p>NEWS SECTION GOES HERE</p>
</div>
<!--div:news_section -->
```

i am trying to tell it to display one if it's a child of WORK page, or else the other div... how would I go about doing this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
if($(this).parent().hasClass('work_section')){
  // your code
} else {
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply hide/show div elements, for example, on a button click. If you have two buttons with a data attribute, you can easily switch between these two pages. Buttons HTML:

```
<div class="button" data-section="work">Work</div>
<div class="button" data-section="news">News</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(".work_section").hide();
    $(".news_section").hide();
    var section=$(this).data("section");
    $("."+section+"_section").show();
});
```

But it can be more precise and readable if you use a section element insted of a div, with shorter class names like "news" and "work". Then your jQuery code will be shorter:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $("section").hide();
    $("."+$(this).data("section")).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this in wordpress.

```
if ( is_page(2) ) {
 // stuff
}
```

or:

```
if ( $post->post_parent == 'WORK' ) {
  // stuff
 }
```

But I am not quiet sure if thats the best way to go about it. Maybe you should rethink how you are are modelling the site.

I would suggest to create 2 different custom post types, work & news. This way you can create instances or posts for each type e.g. single-work.php or single-news.php.

[Codex: Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)

Another way would be to make WORK a category and do custom loop/query and/or conditional statements.